# Angular edit by clicking on a tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using Angular + Firebase + AngularFire to create my own app. I have a table of books, I can add new books and now I want to implement 'edit' action:

1. I click on the row.
2. I'm being redirected to the 'edit' form.
3. All the data must be from the table row I've clicked on.

The problem is about third part, I don't know how to get all the data from the clicked row.

Here is the HTML piece for `<tr>`:

```
<tr ng-click="bookCtrl.editBook(bookCtrl.book)" ng-repeat="book in bookCtrl.books">
    <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ book.author }}</td>
    <td>{{ book.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ book.pubdate | date }}</td>
    <td>{{ book.coverUrl }}</td>
    <td>{{ book.pagesCount}}</td>
</tr>
```

I guess I should use `angular.element(event.currentTarget)` or something similar, but it's just a guess. DOM gurus, please hlep me :)

Comment: what does the editBook function do? Redirect to another page?

Comment: Yes, just redirecr for now.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/m86Lcj9s/

Comment: @Kato yeah, kind of :) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

`<tr ng-click="bookCtrl.editBook(bookCtrl.book)" ng-repeat="book in bookCtrl.books">`

to

`<tr ng-click="bookCtrl.editBook(book)" ng-repeat="book in bookCtrl.books">`

[Similiar example at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/UWLFJ/680/)

Comment: Wow, it works! Could you please give me a brief explanation?

Comment: `ng-repeat` repeater is extracting every object inside `bookCtrl.books`, so the current object would be `book` & not `bookCtrl.book`. when clicked current book object is passed to the edit method .

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to assing the correct object in the function

```
 <tr  ng-repeat="book in bookCtrl.books" ng-click="bookCtrl.editBook(book)">
<td>{{ book.name }}</td>
<td>{{ book.author }}</td>
<td>{{ book.price }}</td>
<td>{{ book.pubdate | date }}</td>
<td>{{ book.coverUrl }}</td>
<td>{{ book.pagesCount}}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope you can access the data from this .

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular grid library, http://ui-grid.info.
Here is a nice article about it, http://brianhann.com/create-a-modal-row-editor-for-ui-grid-in-minutes.

```
function editRow(grid, row) {
    $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'edit-modal.html',
      controller: ['$modalInstance', 'grid', 'row', RowEditCtrl],
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      resolve: {
        grid: function () { return grid; },
        row: function () { return row; }
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $index property of the ng-repeat,  so

```
ng-click="bookCtrl.editBook(bookCtrl.books[$index])" ng-repeat="book in bookCtrl.books track by $index">
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what grid library you use. One angular-based grid library I like to use is trNgGrid. I've also used another library ngDialog with trNgGrid to implement the similar thing you want to do: Pop up a dialog to edit the details for the clicked row.

trNgGrid has some special scope variables `gridItem` and `gridDisplayItem` for that. Quote from documentation:

> Tapping into the currently bound row item can be done through the
>
> `gridItem` scope variable, which points to the actual data item, and
>   `gridDisplayItem`, which points to the formatted item and should only be
>   used for presentation purposes.

Details can be read [here](https://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/#/Customizations_Instance).